# PowerShell : Watch a folder and when file created, send it by mail

Tags: email, powershell, script, shell-script

I would like to create a script watching a specific folder in my computer, and if a new file is created, send this file by email. What I found :

```
$action = {
$WatchFolder = "C:\Users\..."
$To = "maxime@abc.fr"
$From = "no-reply@abc.fr"
$Subject = "New File"
$Body = "New file has been created"
$SMTPServer = "xxx.abc.fr"
     
$Files = (Get-ChildItem $WatchFolder).FullName 
if ($Files) {
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Files
    Remove-Item $Files
}


 Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
 while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Of course it's not working.As you can see I'm a noob with powershell. Someone could help me ? Thanks you guys

Comment: How is it not working? Are there error messages? Also, the SMTP server looks like an email adress, I would expext it to be something like "smtp.abc.fr", but check with the provider for the correct server name.

Comment: The script is just doing nothing. No error message. Also, the SMTP in the script is an example, but I got the good one on my computer. Thank you

Comment: Even if it worked, this approach will perhaps attempt to send the file before it was fully written.

Comment: It will be to transfer files generated by a robot, so the documents will already be complete

Answer (score 2):

I edited a little bit, and it's now working. The solution :

```
    ### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\..."
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### MAIL SETUP

$To = "abc@abc.fr"
$From = "abc@abc.fr"
$Subject = "Exemple"
$Body = "Exemple"
$SMTPServer = "abc.xyz.fr"

      ### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED

$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
       Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $path

          }    

   ### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Thank you for contributions

Comment: FYI and you go down this path using Send-MailMessage. Note that [Send-MailMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage) *** Warning

The Send-MailMessage cmdlet is obsolete. This cmdlet does not guarantee secure connections to SMTP servers. While there is no immediate replacement available in PowerShell, we recommend you do not use Send-MailMessage. *** Look to ```Send-MgUserMail``` and/or ```Send-O365EWSMailMessage```,  if you find yourself in an M365 environmnet.